# How to configure the search bar over the most visited sites on the "new" page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search, about-config

I'd like to use the search bar over the most visited sites tiles on the "new tab" page in Firefox. But currently, my search requests (e.g. "test") get redirected to Yahoo! and a land on the Yahoo! search site (e.g. https://de.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=A111DE105&p=test).

- How can I set this search bar up, so it searchs with Google?

And:

- How can I remove this search bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search engine that this field uses is the same one that Firefox uses overall. What I mean by this is that you will get the same search provider if you enter text into the address bar.

There are a few ways to change this (note that, for this specific question, only the first will apply, but I've added the second for posterity):

## Options menu

- Select the options menu icon (it's located in the top right of the screen by default and looks like three horizontal bars stacked upon each other)
- Find the search bar (found underneath the row with Cut, Copy and Paste and the one with zoom options)
- Click on the icon of your current search provider (or click the down arrow), which should be found on the left of the search bar
- In the subsequent dropdown menu, select the provider that you want to use

[image: Changing the search provider in Firefox using the options menu]

## New tab screen

- Open a new tab
- To the left of the search bar, click on the logo of your current search provider*
- Select the new search provider that you want to use

*This only seems to work for a handful of the search providers. Some examples of working providers are Google, Bing and Wikipedia, as these actually display an icon. Other search providers simply add default text to the search bar to tell you which is currently in use, but do not provide a logo that you are able to click on.

[image: Changing the search provider in Firefox using the new tab screen]